# Need wake lock in IntentService : why go via WakefulBroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-service, android-wake-lock

I have an `IntentService` which is called from elsewhere (say from component X) in my app. I want its `onHandleIntent` to run with a wake lock. There seem to be two ways of doing this:

1. Acquire and release a wake lock in `onHandleIntent`.
2. Create a new `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` which starts this service. In component X, call this receiver instead of the service directly.

The second option seems to be [recommended](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu). But why? Does the added indirection and boilerplate offer any advantage over the first approach?

Answer (score 2):

[Back in 2010](http://androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/44771.html), we were told that the only guarantee with `AlarmManager` and `_WAKEUP`-style alarms was that *if* we used a broadcast `PendingIntent`, *then* Android would keep the device awake long enough for `onReceive()` to complete. Any other type of `PendingIntent` did not have that sort of guarantee.

However, `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver` is called on the main application thread, and we cannot safely spend much time there. Ideally, it's sub-millisecond, as for all you know, your UI happens to be in the foreground right now, and you do not want this receiver to cause jank.

So, the recipe became:

- Have the alarm trigger a `BroadcastReceiver`
- Have the receiver acquire a `WakeLock`
- Have the receiver delegate the work to a `Service`, typically an `IntentService`
- Have the service release the `WakeLock` when the work is completed

[My `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) was the first library to offer support for this recipe. `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` came along later. They both accomplish the same end, just with different semantics.

Note that "why don't we just acquire a `WakeLock` in the service?" fails because the device might fall asleep between the end of `onReceive()` and the first place where the service might get a chance to acquire the `WakeLock`.

Now, for other situations, not involving `AlarmManager`, having the service manage its own `WakeLock` is perfectly reasonable. In fact, that's one of the reasons I went with having a special `IntentService` (`WakefulIntentService`) rather than a special `BroadcastReceiver` (`WakefulBroadcastReceiver`).

Comment: Old Google C2DM library have used the same idea